# Pig output as XML

Tags: xml, hadoop, apache-pig

Wondered if anyone else had come across this problem, and how it is solved.

My Pig script "needs" to output as XML.  The main body builds up XML as follows:

```
<Item><Val1>abc</Val1><Val2>qwe</Val2></Item>

<Item><Val1>tre</Val1><Val2>bnm</Val2></Item>
```

The problem with this is it isn't valid XML.  I need to wrap this like:

```
<Items>
<Item>...</Item>
</Items>
```

But how can this be done in Pig/Hadoop?  The output files are split out across multiple part-XXXXX files, so this can only be done on the merge.

Or maybe XML is completely the wrong approach, and it's always JSON!

Thanks

Duncan

Comment: How are you planning to consume the resulting XML file? It would not be easy consume it in Hadoop. So, you are likely planning to consume it outside HDFS. You would have to export it to your native file system. If your XML structure is simple, you can add <Items> and </Items> lines at that time.

Comment: How big is the output generated (how big are the `part-XXXXX` files prior to being merged)?

Comment: I'll be consuming it outside of Hadoop.  Pig will generate the XML file which will then be consumed by conventional tech.  I'm not expecting it to be huge, maybe a few GB.  But what if the output WAS (theoretically) TB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible solution. You could do a `GROUP ALL` immediately before your `STORE` to ensure only one `part-XXXXX` file is output, this would let you wrap your entire XML block with the desired `<Items>` tag.